# Fabric and Sudo as Another User

Tags: python, postgresql, fabric

Using Fabric to spin up a server, everything works great, except for my attempt to start postgresql.

```
sudo("/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl -D /mnt/ebs/postgresql/data -l /mnt/ebs/logfile start", user='postgres')
```

It outputs "server starting", but it doesn't actually start. Nothing shows up in the postgresql log.

If I ssh in and execute the same command as user `postgres` it works. If I ssh in and run the following, it works as well.

```
 sudo su postgres -c '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl -D /mnt/ebs/postgresql/data -l /mnt/ebs/logfile start
```

What aren't I getting about the way fabric does users? Or the way linux users work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a section](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work) in the docs for your use case. It's related not to the sudo, but to the pty settings of default calls. More info in the FAQ.

Comment: Wow. Right there, first FAQ. Thanks.