# fabric run command as a system user

Tags: python, fabric

How can i switch from the loging user to a system user and run command as that user. Using fabric.

```
def sometask():
    run('mkdir foo')

@hosts(user1@host)
def dothis()
    with change_user(user2):<-- this is what i want to do change user to user2 who is a system user with no password and can't login via ssh
        with cd('~'): <-- cd to users ~
            sometask() <-- run this as user2
            yetanothertask() <-- run this as user2
            .............
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641514/switch-to-different-user-using-fabric and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144430/fabric-and-sudo-as-another-user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could allow simple toggling by using sudo() and have it take as it's user a variable that you toggle with the purposed context manager you want to make. It'd be something that looks a little like:

```
def set_user(user):
    #Make into context manager
    env.custom_user = user

def bar():
    with set_user("foo"):
        execute("sometask")

def sometask():
    sudo("command", user=env.custom_user)
```